# A subsequence converges to 1 with added assumptions implies the original sequence does.

Tags: real-analysis, probability

Let $a_n, b_n$ be positive and non-decreasing. Our goal is to show $\lim \frac{a_n}{b_n} = 1$. Suppose there exists a subsequence ${n_k}$  such that $\frac{a_{n_k}}{b_{n_{k}}} \rightarrow 1$ and $\lim \frac{b_{n_k}}{b_{n_{k+1}}} = 1$.

I was thinking we could do something like: $\frac{a_{n_k}}{b_{n_{k+1}}} \leq \frac{a_{n}}{b_{n}} \leq \frac{a_{n_{k+1}}}{b_{n_{k}}}$, which holds whenever $n_k \leq n \leq n_{k+1}$.

So intuitively this makes sense to me, but I'm looking for an $\epsilon-N$ style argument.

Any tips or solutions? This kind of argument seems to come up a bit in probability and I was looking for a rigorous explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The statement is not true. Let $b_n=n$ and $a_n = 2^{\lceil \log_2 n\rceil}$. Then $a_n/b_n = 1$ if $n=2^a$ for integral $a$, but $a_n/b_n \approx 2$ for $n=2^a+1$.

**UPDATE**

With the updated problem, your intuition is in the right direction. For any $n$, define
$$
f(n) = \max\{ n_k : n_k \le n \}
$$
and
$$
g(n) = \min\{ n_k : n_k \ge n \}.
$$

Observe
$$
\frac{a_{f(n)}}{b_{f(n)}} \frac{b_{f(n)}}{b_{g(n)}} = \frac{a_{f(n)}}{b_{g(n)}}\le\frac{a_n}{b_n} \le \frac{a_{g(n)}}{b_{f(n)}} = \frac{a_{g(n)}}{b_{g(n)}} \frac{b_{g(n)}}{b_{f(n)}}.
$$
Now compute the limits of the expressions on the left and right with the new set of assumptions. Good luck!

Comment: Sorry for the error.  I've modified the hypotheses.  Nice counterexample.

Comment: No problem at all. I've been there.